# How to create such an array by using do loop instead of typing all the number strings?

Tags: arrays, string, vba, loops

The VBA code I am using to obtain the targetted array is :

```
Dim two(100) As String
two(1) = "01"
two(2) = "02"
two(3) = "03"
two(4) = "04"
two(5) = "05"
two(6) = "06"
two(7) = "07"
two(8) = "08"
two(9) = "09"
two(10) = "10"
two(11) = "11"
two(12) = "12"
two(13) = "13"
two(14) = "14"
two(15) = "15"
two(16) = "16"
two(17) = "17"
two(18) = "18"
two(19) = "19"
two(20) = "20"
two(21) = "21"
two(22) = "22"
two(23) = "23"
two(24) = "24"
two(25) = "25"
two(26) = "26"
two(27) = "27"
two(28) = "28"
two(29) = "29"
two(30) = "30"
two(31) = "31"
two(32) = "32"
two(33) = "33"
two(34) = "34"
two(35) = "35"
two(36) = "36"
two(37) = "37"
two(38) = "38"
two(39) = "39"
two(40) = "40"
two(41) = "41"
two(42) = "42"
two(43) = "43"
two(44) = "44"
two(45) = "45"
two(46) = "46"
two(47) = "47"
two(48) = "48"
two(49) = "49"
two(50) = "50"
two(51) = "51"
two(52) = "52"
two(53) = "53"
two(54) = "54"
two(55) = "55"
two(56) = "56"
two(57) = "57"
two(58) = "58"
two(59) = "59"
two(60) = "60"
two(61) = "61"
two(62) = "62"
two(63) = "63"
two(64) = "64"
two(65) = "65"
two(66) = "66"
two(67) = "67"
two(68) = "68"
two(69) = "69"
two(70) = "70"
two(71) = "71"
two(72) = "72"
two(73) = "73"
two(74) = "74"
two(75) = "75"
two(76) = "76"
two(77) = "77"
two(78) = "78"
two(79) = "79"
two(80) = "80"
two(81) = "81"
two(82) = "82"
two(83) = "83"
two(84) = "84"
two(85) = "85"
two(86) = "86"
two(87) = "87"
two(88) = "88"
two(89) = "89"
two(90) = "90"
two(91) = "91"
two(92) = "92"
two(93) = "93"
two(94) = "94"
two(95) = "95"
two(96) = "96"
two(97) = "97"
two(98) = "98"
two(99) = "98"
two(100) = "100"
```

I also tried:

```
Dim two() As String
two = Split("00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,", ",")
```

Both the two programming style require a lot of character typing (though the use of spreadsheet may loose the burden).

How can I create such an array inside a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dim I as integer
redim two(100)
for I = 1 to 100
   two(I)=format(cstr(I),"00")
next I
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.